# How can ancestors leave a makom l'hisgader?

Tags: avodah-zarah, melachim-kings-book-of, chulin-tractate, halachic-development

The gemara in חולין on 6b / 7a (apologies, on mobile so can't provide link) discusses how the copper snake of Moshe should have been destroyed by earlier Kings (specifically referring to those kings who were righteous and aware of the issue), as it was being used for avodah zarah, but it was left to חזקיה as מקום הניחו אבותיו להתגדר בו. If there was a genuine avodah zara issue going on, how could it be intentionally left for חזקיה to fix? If there wasn't an issue, in what sense have the earlier Kings left a place להתגדר?

I am assuming that מקום הניחו לו means that it was intentionally left for later generations, based on Rashi Chullin 7a -

> מקום הניחו - כשיבאו בנינו אחרינו אם לא ימצאו מה לתקן במה יגדל שמם
>   When our children come after us, if they don't find anything to fix, how will their name become great?

Comment: Are you asking how could it be that previous generations weren't perfect? If you accept that then what is surprising about their having left you room for improvement?

Comment: The snake was a mitzvah object created by Moshe.  Even though destroying it was the right thing to do under the circumstances, I can see them being reluctant to do it.

Comment: @DoubleAA I think he is understanding "מקום הניחו אבותיו להתגדר בו" as meaning they _intentionally_ left to him (or any other future generation) the opportunity of fixing the problem. Moshe Steinberg, if this is your understanding of "מקום הניחו אבותיו להתגדר בו", you should edit that into the question.

Comment: @TamirEvan yes, that was very much my assumption. Thanks for your point; I have added this to the question

Comment: Previous generations struggled with the desire for avodah zarah the same way we struggle with the desire for forbidden sexual relations. Chazekeia's father was an out-and-out idol worshipper who closed down the Beit HaMikdash and installed an altar to Moloch in the courtyard.....is it surprising he would not stop idol worship?

Comment: Later commentators are universally confounded by this Rashi. Some, like the Maharsha ([ad loc.](https://www.sefaria.org/Chidushei_Agadot_on_Chullin.7a)), reinterpret Rashi to mean that Chizkiyahu's ancestors were made by Heaven to be oblivious to the need to act. Others, like the *Nachalas Shiva* (*Hakdama*) say it must be copyist error or an erroneous student, and Rashi meant "בניהם אחריהם" ("their children after them" rather than "our children after us", which allows Rashi to be read according to the Maharsha's interpretation), and perhaps that is implicitly the Maharsha's take as well.

Comment: @JoshK The question was talking more about kings like Asa and Yehoshaphat  mentioned in the cited passage in Chulin [as having eradicated all objects of idol worship in the world](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Chullin.6b.7?lang=bi&lang2=en).

Comment: The general approach to this question is either that 1) Chizkiyahu realized the enormity of the problem and his predecessors did not (Maharsha), 2) the view of Tosafos (ad loc.) who says the previous leaders were of the mistaken opinion that it was forbidden to destroy it since it was originally created by Divine command, or 3) a hybrid interpretation that it normally would be forbidden to destroy, but Chizkiyahu realized that the seriousness of the situation necessitated radical action.

Comment: @Fred can you put that as an answer?